# After indexing items are not visible, solr server

Tags: 7, commerce, search, queue

After indexing the items aren't visible on the page. The index does work, but after refreshing the page, the indexed items aren't shown on the page.

View index > Queue all items for reindexing > Index now > {the indexing operation works but the items don't show}

I installed the facet api and search api again, but nothing changes.

Warning messages in solr:

```
XML parse warning in "solrres:/schema.xml",​ line 537,​ column 89: Include operation failed,​ reverting to fallback. Resource error reading file as XML (href='schema_extra_fields.xml'). Reason: Can't find resource 'schema_extra_fields.xml' in classpath or '/Users/{namePC}/Desktop/solr-4.10.2/drupal-search/solr/collection1/conf'

Multiple requestHandler registered to the same name: /update ignoring: org.apache.solr.handler.UpdateRequestHandler

[collection1] PERFORMANCE WARNING: Overlapping onDeckSearchers=2
```

I'm using a solr server. Does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: Would it be possible to have more information.  Where fo the items not show.  Are you using views to display the returned information. Thanks

Comment: Updated my question and yeah I'm using views.

Comment: Thanks, I think the issue looks like a Solr Server setup issue.  in which case I can't help with this one, as this is something I leave to our hosts.  Sorry.